# Can we schedule multiple NodePools of the same cluster at the same time using Cloud Scheduler in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloud, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-scheduler

I have written a cloud function for scaling up/down the multiple node pools of the same cluster at the same time.

```
import json
from google.cloud import container_v1
from google.cloud.container_v1.types import cluster_service

def scale_up_node_pools(event, context):
    """Scales up node pools of a given GKE cluster"""
    if 'data' in event:
        payload = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
        payload = json.loads(payload)
    else:
        print('Error: Invalid Pub/Sub message format')
        return

    # Extracting data from the Pub/Sub message
    project_id = payload.get('projectId')
    location = payload.get('location')
    cluster_name = payload.get('cluster_name')
    num_nodes = payload.get('num_nodes')

    # Instantiating a client
    client = container_v1.ClusterManagerClient()

    # Retrieving the cluster
    cluster_path = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/clusters/{cluster_name}"
    request = cluster_service.GetClusterRequest(name=cluster_path)
    cluster = client.get_cluster(request=request)
    
    # Scaling up each node pool
    for node_pool in cluster.node_pools:
        node_pool_name = node_pool.name
        print(f'Scaling up node pool: {node_pool_name}')

        request = cluster_service.SetNodePoolSizeRequest(
            name=f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/clusters/{cluster_name}/nodePools/{node_pool_name}",
            node_count=num_nodes
        )
        # Updating the node pool
        operation = client.set_node_pool_size(request=request)
```

For this I am passing below json payload through pub/sub in a scheduler job

```
{
  "projectId": "",
  "location": "",
  "cluster_name": "",
  "num_nodes": 1
}
```

But I am getting multiple errors:

1. TypeError: ClusterManagerClient.set_node_pool_size() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 6 were given
2. ValueError: Unknown field for SetNodePoolSizeRequest: cluster_name
3. ValueError: Unknown field for SetNodePoolSizeRequest: location

Please help me to understand, What are the problems in the above code?

**Update** - Now this function started working, but it is failing after one iteration of loop. Because, Google doesn't allow multiple node pools scale up/down at the same time. Scaling up/down takes some time but before scaling up/down of first node pools ends, loop is going in second iteration where it is trying to scale up/down second node pool that's why it is giving error.

Can someone suggest how to hold the iteration until the current operation ends, and only after that loop should go for second iteration?

Answer (score 0):

While I have not used or looked at that particular client library, looking [here](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/container/latest/google.cloud.container_v1beta1.services.cluster_manager.ClusterManagerClient) indicates that you might want to try using
`from google.cloud import container_v1beta1` and then have a look at the request parameters to see if they match with yours. Have a look at how they create the request using SetNodePoolSizeRequest and then pass the that as `request` into `set_node_pool_size`.

Hopefully this link gets you closer to the right answer.